# How to add street view in google maps for some specific area?

Tags: google-maps, google-earth, area, google-street-view

I need to know how to add a street view of some specific area on google maps or google earth. Is that possible?

Comment: I would think you would have to get in touch with Google

Answer (score 3):

Google is interested in the highest quality and properly captured images for their street view inventory. Here are the ways I found images are included for street view.

There are two sources by which Google street view gets it's image, one is through Google own resources (i.e. vehicles, cameras etc...). The other is user generated, you could read more [here](https://www.google.com/streetview/understand/)

In addition, you could access information [here](https://www.google.com/streetview/publish/) where you can identify the specific image capture tool that works for you.

Comment: I think he's after how to add images to street view rather than how to view street view images...

Comment: Yea, I believe you are correct.

Comment: Yes, I want to add pictures to street view but I dont know is that possible to do.

Comment: Yes it is. check my answer to see how